# Docker compose, manage environments

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment

I have the following `docker-compose.yml` file to work locally:

```
mongodb:
  image: mongo
  command: "--smallfiles --logpath=/dev/null"
web:
  build: .
  command: npm run dev
  volumes:
    - .:/myapp
  ports:
    - "3001:3000"
  links:
    - mongodb
  environment:
    PORT: 3000
    NODE_ENV: 'development'
seed:
 build: ./seed
 links:
   - mongodb
```

When I deploy to my server, I need to change two things in the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
web:
  command: npm start
  environment:
    NODE_ENV: 'production'
```

I guess editing the file after each deploy ain't the most comfortable way to do that. Any suggestion on how to cleanly manage environments in the `docker-compose.yml` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way is to use a Compose overrides file. By default docker-compose reads two files at startup, `docker-compose.yml` and `docker-compose.override.yml`. You can put anything you want to override in the latter. So:

```
# docker-compose.yml
mongodb:
  image: mongo
  command: "--smallfiles --logpath=/dev/null"
web:
  build: .
  command: npm run dev
  volumes:
    - .:/myapp
  ports:
    - "3001:3000"
  links:
    - mongodb
  environment:
    PORT: 3000
    NODE_ENV: 'development'
seed:
  build: ./seed
  links:
    - mongodb
```

Also:

```
# docker-compose.override.yml
web:
  command: npm start
  environment:
    NODE_ENV: 'production'
```

Then you can run `docker-compose up` and will get the production settings. If you just want dev then you can run `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up`.

An even better way is to name your compose files in a relevant way. So, `docker-compose.yml` becomes `development.yml` and `docker-compose.override.yml` becomes `production.yml` or something. Then you can run `docker-compose -f development -f production up` for production, and just `docker-compose -f development` for development. You may also want to look into the `extends` [functionality](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/) of docker-compose.

Answer (score 0):

Just try using my way.

[This is](https://github.com/kartoza/projecta) an example of my django project that I've run on docker.

1. First in [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/kartoza/projecta/blob/develop/deployment/docker-compose.yml) you have to defined two containers.
   First is `web` it means for production then second is `devweb` it
   means for development.
2. If you use dockerfile you can create separated dockerfile
   ([Dockerfile](https://github.com/kartoza/projecta/blob/develop/deployment/docker/Dockerfile) : for production, and [Dockerfile-dev](https://github.com/kartoza/projecta/blob/develop/deployment/docker/Dockerfile-dev) for development).

By that you can run by using docker-compose command. 
For example :

1. `docker-compose -p $(PROJECT) up -d web` for production
2. `docker-compose -p $(PROJECT) up --no-deps -d devweb` for
   development

Anyway, I use [Makefile](https://github.com/kartoza/projecta/blob/develop/deployment/Makefile) to manage all docker-compose's command, and its make me very easy. I just need to run `make command name`  to execute a command.

May this answer help you.